# Who can become king of the Jews?

Tags: malchut-royalty, king-david

The Talmud says:

> חכם קודם למלך ישראל חכם שמת אין לנו כיוצא בו מלך ישראל שמת כל ישראל ראוים
> למלכות
> -- A Torah Sage comes before the king of Israel, because if a Sage dies, we have no one like him to replace him, but if a king of Israel dies, all of Israel are fit for royalty. [Horayot 13a]

Doesn't a king of the Jews have to descend from King David?

Comment: Are you referring to passages such as 1 Kings 2:33, 2:45, 9:5; Isaiah 9:7; Jeremiah 17:25, 33:17 ? If so, then please note that a naive or simplistic interpretation of at least some of them is easily disproved by either scripture or history.

Comment: Midrash Tanchuma Parshat Bo עד שלא נבחר דוד היו כל ישראל ראויים למלכות משנבחר דוד יצאו כל ישראל

Comment: @Alex But the Chashmonaim still became kings? (Yes I know what the Ramban says, but nevertheless no-one at the time objected to the arrangement)

Comment: this question is discussed here but I don't understand it well enough to present an answer https://www.sefaria.org/Horayot.13a.10?lang=he&with=Commentary%20on%20Sefer%20Hamitzvot%20of%20Rasag|Quoting&lang2=he

Comment: I can name dozens of kings of Jews who weren't descended from David. Why do you think they have to descend from David?

Answer (score 8):

See Rambam Hilchot Melachim Chapter 1.

Any Jew can be appointed king as long as he is not a convert nor descended exclusively from converts (Law 4), a woman (Law 5) nor currently or previously employed in a dishonorable profession (Law 6).

Although the Davidic line was promised everlasting kingship (Law 7), **a king from any tribe, appointed by a prophet, and who behaves appropriately, has the status of a king** (Law 8). However, such a king's line of succession will eventually cease (Law 9). He also cannot reign in Jerusalem (Law 10).

Answer (score 0):

See the [Rav Yerucham Fischel Perla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerucham_Fishel_Perlow)'s [commentary on Sefer Hamitzvos of Rav Sadia Gaon](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Communal_Laws.7?lang=he), where he proves definitively, with proofs from all over the place, that a king may be appointed from any Shevet.

Comment: Can you summarize one or a few of his proofs?